# Table formatting: how to merge some column headers?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Please help me to split the cells in my table.

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline 
    XX  & XXX & XXXX & XXX & XXXX \\ 
         \hline
    xxx & xxx & xx & xx & xx \\ 

    yyy & y & yy & yy & yyy \\ 

    zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

Its output is:

[image]

I need the output like below by merging some columns:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline 
    \multirow{2}{*}{XX}  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} \\ 
        \cline{3-5} 
      &  & XXXX & XXX & XXXX \\ 
         \hline
    xxx & xxx & xx & xx & xx \\ 

    yyy & y & yy & yy & yyy \\ 

    zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Although it's better to avoid vertical rules as suggested by [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
        \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}[-3pt]{XX}  & \multirow{2}{*}[-3pt]{XX} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\ 
        \cmidrule{3-5} 
      &  & XXXX & XXX & XXXX \\ 
         \midrule
    xxx & xxx & xx & xx & xx \\ 

    yyy & y & yy & yy & yyy \\ 

    zzz & zz & zz & zzzz & zz \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest to use `\usepackage{array} \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.3}` to improve the first table of your solution.